# elasticsearch nest: create SearchRequest with multi Aggregations using the object initializer syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am looking for how to init a SearchRequest Object with several no nested Aggregations by using the object initializer syntax.

If the request were given as param into ElasticClient.Search() with lambda expression helper it would be written like bellow:

```cs
var response = Client.Search<person>(s => s.Aggregations(a => 
        a.Terms("bucketAge", t => t.Field("age").Size(50))
         .Terms("bucketCity", t => t.Field("city").Size(50))));
```

What is paradoxical is i found i how to write a Agg with a nested Agg

```cs
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<person>
{
    Size = 0,
    Aggregations =  new TermsAggregation("bucketAge")
    {
       Field = "age",
       Size = 50,
       Aggregations = new TermsAggregation("bucketcity")
        {
            Field = "city",
            Size = 50
        }
    }
};
```

But i fail to init SearchRequest with 2 aggs on same level with Something like that:

```cs
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<person>
{
    Size = 0,
    Aggregations =
    {
        new TermsAggregation("bucketAge")
        {
          Field = "age",
          Size = 50
        },
        new TermsAggregation("bucketcity")
        {
          Field = "city",
          Size = 50
        }
     }
 };
```

How to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Object Initializer syntax, you can combine aggregations with `&&`

```cs
var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<person>
{
    Size = 0,
    Aggregations =
      new TermsAggregation("bucketAge")
      {
          Field = "age",
          Size = 50
      } &&
      new TermsAggregation("bucketcity")
      {
          Field = "city",
          Size = 50
      }

};

var searchResponse = client.Search<person>(searchRequest);
```

You can use the longer winded method using an aggregation dictionary if you prefer

```cs
var aggregations = new Dictionary<string, AggregationContainer>
{
    { "bucketAge", new TermsAggregation("bucketAge")
      {
          Field = "age",
          Size = 50
      }
    },
    { "bucketcity", new TermsAggregation("bucketcity")
      {
          Field = "city",
          Size = 50
      }
    },
};

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<person>
{
    Size = 0,
    Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary(aggregations)
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<person>(searchRequest);
```

Note that the keys in the `Dictionary<string, AggregationContainer>` will be the names of the aggregations in the request.

Comment: thank you really much! your answere ireally well explained and  full. is exist a link where all of thoses aspects of nest are explained? i found just one page where i can see an example where && is shown but i am affraid i did not search with the correct terms.

Comment: @lambdaDev did you see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/writing-aggregations.html ?